# how can we define blocks in sonata

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I checked the documentation of sonatablockbundle and they say nothing about what do we mean by blocks, there are mentions about what do we have (twig helpers, provided blocks ...) in this bundle but not about what are the they
so if someone would explain me what is a block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's twig specifications not a sonata one